# (Android) Leer texto desde fichero en web

Tags: java, android

estoy haciendo una aplicacion en la cual necesito leer una cadena de un fichero alojado en un hosting y la muestre en un Toast, con el código que adjunto funciona sin problemas desde Eclipse pero en Android Studio no logro hacer que me obtenga dicha cadena. ¿Alguna idea, solución?.

```
public String lee ()throws Exception{

     URL url = new URL("http://radios-android.000webhostapp.com/fichero_web.txt");
     URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
     InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

     String linea = br.readLine();

    br.close();return linea;
}
public void muestra_toast (View v) throws Exception{
        String cadena = new String();

       try{
           cadena=lee();
       }catch (Exception e){}

        Toast.makeText(this, cadena, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

[image: Eclipse]

---

Este error lanza al tocar en el cardview que llama a la funcion y la app se cae:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: mazcvei.login_screen, PID: 5409
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716) 
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                   Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:220)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:176)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:501)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:484)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:372)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:418)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:235)
                      at mazcvei.login_screen.MainActivity.lee(MainActivity.java:26)
                      at mazcvei.login_screen.MainActivity.muestra_toast(MainActivity.java:37)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716) 
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Podrías aportar que error te lanza en Android Studio? y aparte mira si has añadido los permisos de acceso a internet en el manifiesto de tu aplicación.

Comment: Los permisos de acceso a internet están añadidos, no aporta ningun error en concreto pero si pongo un toast justo despues de "InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();" este no se ejecuta, en general la funcion  lee() es llamada pero no devuelve nada.

Comment: No devuelve error porque tienes la llamada a la funcion lee()  encapsulada en un try catch. Elimina el try catch o imprime la excepcion que devuelve el catch.

Comment: El error  at mazcvei.login_screen.MainActivity.lee(MainActivity.java:26) hace referencia a la instruccion de InputStream

Comment: lo conseguiste amigo estoy en lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Viendo la excepción que posteaste te contesto ya con la respuesta:
La excepción clave es [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) la cual se lanza porque estás intentando llevar a cabo una operación de red en el hilo principal (main thread) de android.
Toda operación de red **debe de llamarse en un hilo secundario.**

Para ello te recomiendo que uses [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) que ya implementa toda la lógica y te va a facilitar el trabajo.

Como tu código es simple y a lo mejor solo quieres implementar algo mas fácil, puedes usar un Thread tal que así:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
             //llamada a la operación de red aquí
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Con esta clase puedes descargar cosas de una web.

```
public class Download extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String linea = br.readLine();
        br.close();
        return linea;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("DOWNLOAd", result);
    }
}
```

Así lo mandarías a llamar desde la clase donde lo vas a ocupar.

```
Download task = new Download();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://radios-android.000webhostapp.com/fichero_web.txt"});
```